# How to stop a Delayed Job from running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Can I use the hooks of a delayed job to stop it before running?

If so how?

```rb
class Jobs::SomeJob < Struct.new
  
  def before(job)
    if should_not_run_job
      # Do I raise an exception?
      # Is there an official way to stop a Job from running?
    end
  end
  
  def perform
   # Working...
  end
 

  def queue_name
    return "SomeJob";
  end

end
```

Do I raise an error?
Which hook is recommended to use?

Answer (score 2):

Raising an exception wouldn't work because then the retry mechanism would kick in and would retry running the job a couple of times.

Instead, I would just add a guard clause that in the first line of the `perform` method that returns without doing anything when the conditions is not `true` anymore. It depends on how your condition looks but something like this might work for you:

```
def perform
  return if job_should_not_run_anymore?

  # Working
end

private

def job_should_not_run_anymore?
  # Condition
end
```

When your condition is based on the `job` itself that is only available in a hook method like `before` but not in the `perform` method then I would store the result of the condition in an instance variable and check that variable in the perform method like this:

```
def before(job)
  @outdated = job.run_at > 15.minutes.ago
end

def perform
  return if @outdated

  # Working
end
```

Comment: I need the `job` argument to perform my condition, how do get it in the `perform` method ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how your condition looks like?

Comment: Yes.

My condition involves around the `run_at` column of the jobs table.
After X time, I would like to stop the operation.
Example: `stop if job.run_at > 15.minutes.ago`

However, I've never seen an example where the `job` argument is used in the `perform` method, which is why I'm asking if I can even access it from there.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment, @tazmazia

Comment: Kind of tedious to use instance methods to share data between the methods, but it works!